# How do I insert multiple checkbox values with different name?

Tags: php, yii

I want to store multiple checkbox value in database ,and my checkbox name is differnt,how can save ??.I have three column like Called them,Called you,toured, how i can store each value in data base.

```
 HTML Code


 <input type="checkbox" name="Called_them[]" value="1">1<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Called_them[]" value="2">2<br>


 <input type="checkbox" name="Called_you[]" value="1">1<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Called_you[]" value="2">2<br>
```

PHP Code:-

```
     if(isset($_POST['submits']) )

    {
        $checked = $_POST['alled_them'];
        $checked1 = isset($_POST['alled_them']);
        for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
        $tellfriend=new MemberEmails;
        $tellfriend->called_them = isset($checked[$i])==0?'':$checked[i];
        $tellfriend->save();
            }
```

Comment: Maybe you have made a typo, because i see `Called_them[]` as name attribute in your HTML, while in PHP, you're using `alled_them` as key element to get your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    foreach($_POST['called_them'] as $called_them) {
    //do things
    }
    foreach($_POST['called_you'] as $called_you) {
    // do things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_called_them = $_POST['called_them'];
$array_called_them = $_POST['called_you];
```

You now have both checkbox groups as arrays. if you want the value from the array just use foreach on each of the arrays.